# What are these black lines under the tabs?

Tags: chords, tablature

[image]

What are these black lines that's under the tabs? Are they there for rhythm or something?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they indicate rhythm. This is hybrid form of tab that combines numeric notation with the rhythmic part of traditional notation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, where can I learn more about these?

Comment: @user65342 just try googling reading music rhythm or something similar. There are numerous videos and websites that can explain the basic to you.

Comment: search "tab with rhythm" to start @65432